# Mostrando tamanho total de um diretório

Tags: php

Ola gostaria de saber como posso mostrar o tamanho total de um diretório sendo que preciso que o script fique numa pasta chamada status e mostre os dados da pasta formatos/hd/.

Eu achei esse código abaixo com tudo ele só monstra o espaço ocupado se o arquivo estiver dentro do diretório. Alguém poderia me ajudar.

```
<?php 
    $bytes = disk_free_space("."); 
    $si_prefix = array( 'B', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB' );
    $base = 1024;
    $class = min((int)log($bytes , $base) , count($si_prefix) - 1);
    echo 'Espa&ccedil;o total do FTP da pasta formatos/hd/ '. sprintf('%1.2f' , $bytes / pow($base,$class)) . ' ' . $si_prefix[$class] . '<br />';
?>
```

Comment: Necessitas do tamanho total do directório ou o espaço livre em disco? Porque a função disk_free_space() devolve o espaço livre e não o espaço ocupado.

Comment: No caso então come seria pra por o espaço ocupado ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta solução deverá funcionar em qualquer plataforma com php 5 ou superior.

```
function GetDirectorySize($path){
    $bytestotal = 0;
    $path = realpath($path);
    if($path!==false){
        foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS)) as $object){
            $bytestotal += $object->getSize();
        }
    }
    return $bytestotal;
}
```

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda.